# Have a Strategy that does not uniformly choose between different strategies

Tags: python-hypothesis

I'd like to create a strategy C that, 90% of the time chooses strategy A, and 10% of the time chooses strategy B.

The random python library does not work even if I seed it since each time the strategy produces values, it generates the same value from random.

I looked at the implementation for OneOfStrategy and they use 
            i = cu.integer_range(data, 0, n - 1)
to randomly generate a number

cu is from the internals
import hypothesis.internal.conjecture.utils as cu

Would it be fine for my strategy to use cu.integer_range or is there another implementation?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you show us what you've got so far?  Check out [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we have enough information to properly help you.

Answer (score 3):

Hypothesis does not allow users to control the probability of various choices within a strategy.  You should not use undocumented interfaces either - `hypothesis.internal` is for internal use only and could break at any time!

I strongly recommend using `C = st.one_of(A, B)` and trusting Hypothesis with the details.

Comment: What i'm using hypothesis for is to generate RPC against a server. I disabled the use_coverage setting because it would have done coverage on the client (which I'm not interested in since it is a very simiple client). My goal with hypothesis is to generate variety of traffic against the server. I did `choice = data.draw(st.sampled_from(range(1, 10)))` since sampled_from is suppose to be uniform. Depending on the value of choice, I choose a strategy. Would this work? If not, what do you suggest instead for my use case

Comment: Sampling is **not** supposed to be uniform; Hypothesis never gives you a specific distribution.  As above, "I strongly recommend using [`C = st.one_of(A, B)`"!](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.one_of)